# How to read a CSV? ERROR message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really stuck once more.

For my coursework the question is

> Find the sum of the values in the field [age] less than 47 which is from 3 CSV files

ok so I found the problem and it is now fixed!! But i'm now getting an error when I use the "SUM" function.

again here is my code... sorry if i'm wasting your time guys.

```
import csv
myFile = csv.reader(open('3028571a.csv', newline=''), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

next(myFile)

for record in myFile:
   records = int(record[0])
   if records < 47:
        sum(records)
        print(records)
```

its like five records but the error i receive is

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

thats for the sum bit... any suggestions? I cant think of anything hence the reason i have asked.

Comment: Is this seriously the extent of your efforts?

Comment: You should read about the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html), and look at the examples it gives. First thing you should notice is that the examples don't use a naked `open` to open the file; they instead use `csv.reader` to wrap the file.

Comment: I'd ask because this is a homework: are you expected to parse CSV data by hand (i.e. you're learning about file access and string manipulation) or you're allowed to use `csv` module?

Comment: parse so I am not allowed to edit the CSV source file.

Comment: @Bilal Haider:  Should be the task done in Python (i.e., can you use the ready to be used string methods like `.split()`?  How complex the CSV file is? Can you show the fragment?

Comment: drdaeman asks you if you are allowed to use the `csv` module.  If not, you have to write your own parser.  But you can get inspired by the `csv` module.  For example, you can convert each line into a list of elements.

Comment: Why did you think you should put the delimiter to ' '?

Comment: Have you considered using a `csv.DictReader` to deal with your header row?

Comment: Edits seem to have changed the scope of this question radically, making the answers not .. make much sense .. any longer. Perhaps you wanted to just ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

Python already has an excellent CSV parser, handling various delimiters, escaped delimiters, etc. It's called `csv.reader` and it's in the `csv` module. You can use it as follows:

```
sum(int(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(open(f, "rb")) for f in files if int(row[0]) < 47)
```

Of course, this isn't really doing the homework -- it's just using Python's built-in tools to do it for you. If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to read each line of the file manually, split it based on the separator, maybe worry about commas in quotes (which shouldn't count as commas)... in other words, re-implement `csv.reader`!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably of some use to you: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Basically, you pass the csv.reader() function a file handle, then you can loop across the rows.

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
import csv
import sys

agecol = 1
namecol = 0
agelimit = 47

def sum_ages(files):
    agesum = 0
    for f in files:
        with open(f, 'r') as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp)
            for row in reader:
                age = int(row[agecol])
                name = row[namecol]
                if age < agelimit:
                    print 'Adding %s\'s age (%d)' % (name, age)
                    agesum += age
                else:
                    print 'Skipping %s\'s age (%d)' % (name, age)

    print 'Sum of Ages < %d: %d' % (agelimit, agesum)
```

Comment: It is important to follow the doc.  The file must be opened for reading in binary mode.  For homework, it is also important to keep the code clean -- the `open()` must be paired with `.close()` or the `with` construct should be used.  It is also good to keep the conventions suggested by the Python documentation as it will not look *unusual* to the others.  For example, the `csv.reader()` is usually assigned to the `reader` variable.  Also the `files` should be `filenames`.

Comment: Wanted to leave some work to the OP.  Don't disagree re: using a real file handle and close()ing it.  But, variable names?  Really?

Comment: Yes. Variable names are extremely important to avoid confusion.  For example, `f` is usually used for a file object (open file).  In Python, you are not working with a *file handle*.  Also any *file handle* cannot be closed.  A file handle only represents a file object (implemented as a data structure).  The `i` used for a string would be confusing.  I am sure you understand the details, but students are beginners and they should not be misleaded towards confusion.

Comment: @pepr: To nitpick, the file should *not* be open in binary mode, since the question is about Python 3. It should be open in text mode, but without any newline translation (i.e. with the parameter `newline=''`). [Docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv#csv.reader)

Comment: @Thomas K: Thanks for pointing this out.  My +1.  Frankly, I was not aware of this in Python 3.  But yes, the goal is to let the csv parser decide what is the newline sequence and what is not.  The binary mode in Python 2 was the way, as Python 2 *classical, usual* strings where sequences of bytes.  This simplification is not possible in Python 3 any more. ;)